# Savon 2.1 adding attributes to message XML tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

I am currently trying to add an atribute to one of the xml elements I am generating for the SOAP  request I am making.

I see savon has an attributes hash, but that only adds attributes to the soap message tag. Is there an equivalent feature that I have not come across for the generated XML in the message body?

IE say I have a tag in my message body

```
    <ClientData></ClientData>
```

I would like to be able to be able to something like

```
     <ClientData id=1></ClientData>
```

Is this possible with using Savon hash syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Well ended up digging into Gyoku(the gem Savon uses to form the xml) and found that it has a special hash called by :attributes! key. calling this and passing in a hash of the elements with the specified attribues and value did exactly what I needed.

IE for what I asked aove

```
    :attributes! => { "ClientData => { :id => 1 } }
```

at the end of the :message option did the trick.